# Does mockjax could capture all ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, mockjax

I am planning to use Mockjax for one of my offline applications. Will Mockjax capture the ajax calls made even by extjs or other javascript libarires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends... if you are referring to the original [mockjax jQuery plugin](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax) then it will only work with jQuery's `$.ajax()` method calls. That said, there are other libraries out there called "Mockjax" which do similar things.

If you need a more "generic" solution that will work with other libraries (or just vanilla JavaScript) then I would recommend looking into the [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) library.